# Vue Composable Functions & Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, monaco-editor

I'm trying to abstract some repetitive functions to update parts of the Monaco edit from various check boxs in the UI. The example below enables or disables linenumber in the editor.

Works fine when the editor and functions are in the same setup. When I abstract to a composable per below the editor is null, therefore does not work. Any thoughts or ideas?

Note: Some code is removed for brevity

MainTemplate.vue

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import useCodeEditor from '../composables/codeEditorFunctions';
import { ref, onMounted, reactive, inject, watch } from 'vue';
export default {
    setup(props, { emit }) {
        let meditor = null;
        onMounted(() => {
                checkDarkModeIsSet();
                checkLineNumbersIsSet();
                checkMiniMapIsSet();

            const codeEditorDiv = document.getElementById('pf-c-code-editor__code-pre');
            meditor = monaco.editor.create(codeEditorDiv, {
                value: ['function x() {', '\tconsole.log("If you see this, something went wrong!");', '}'].join('\n'),
                language: 'yaml',
                lineNumbers: lineNumbers.value,
                roundedSelection: false,
                scrollBeyondLastLine: true,
                readOnly: false,
                theme: darkmode.value,
                scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
                automaticLayout: true,
                wordWrap: 'on',
                wrappingStrategy: 'advanced',
                minimap: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            });
            if (props.viewstate.editid === 0) {
                getDefaultCodeBlock();
            } else {
                showCodeBlock();
            }
            getModel(props.viewstate.editid);
        });

    const { darkmode, checkDarkModeIsSet, toggleEditorDarkMode, lineNumbers, checkLineNumbersIsSet, toggleEditorLineNumbers } = useCodeEditor(monaco, meditor);

    return {
        darkmode,
        lineNumbers,
        toggleEditorDarkMode,
        toggleEditorLineNumbers,
        toggleEditorMinimap,
        showConfigFullScreen
    };
    }
};
```

codeEditorFunctions.js

```
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

export default function useCodeEditor(monaco, meditor) {
/** EDITOR DARKMODE */
const darkmode = ref('vs');

function checkDarkModeIsSet() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('editordarkmode') === null) {
        darkmode.value = 'vs';
        localStorage.setItem('editordarkmode', darkmode.value);
    } else {
        darkmode.value = localStorage.getItem('editordarkmode');
    }
}

function toggleEditorDarkMode(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        darkmode.value = 'vs-dark';
        localStorage.setItem('editordarkmode', darkmode.value);
    } else {
        darkmode.value = 'vs';
        localStorage.setItem('editordarkmode', darkmode.value);
    }
    monaco.editor.setTheme(darkmode.value);
}

/** EDITOR LINNUMBERS */
const lineNumbers = ref('on');

function checkLineNumbersIsSet() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('editorlineNumbers') === null) {
        lineNumbers.value = 'on';
        localStorage.setItem('editorlineNumbers', lineNumbers.value);
    } else {
        lineNumbers.value = localStorage.getItem('editorlineNumbers');
    }
}

function toggleEditorLineNumbers(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        lineNumbers.value = 'on';
        localStorage.setItem('editorlineNumbers', lineNumbers.value);
    } else {
        lineNumbers.value = 'off';
        localStorage.setItem('editorlineNumbers', lineNumbers.value);
    }
    meditor.updateOptions({
        lineNumbers: lineNumbers.value
    });
}

  return {
    darkmode,
    checkDarkModeIsSet,
    toggleEditorDarkMode,
    lineNumbers,
    checkLineNumbersIsSet,
    toggleEditorLineNumbers,

  };
};
```

Basically, function toggleEditorLineNumbers(event) throws an error becuase meditor (meditor.updateOptions) is null.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the case for a ref, which basically is a recipe that allows to pass arbitrary value by reference. Since `meditor` isn't supposed to be used prior to `useCodeEditor` call, it makes more sense to define it inside a composable instead of providing it as an argument:

```
function useCodeEditor(monaco) {
  const meditor = ref(null);
  ...
  return {
    meditor,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I ended up doing. Moving the following inside the same composable, inside a function and returning and calling that function in the component.
Thanks!